# Описание протокола общения с IP камерой

Tags: php, tcp, камера, протоколы

Имеется камера HikVision DS-2CD2012-I. Необходимо иметь возможность получать информацию о ее состоянии (в перспективе и попробовать стримить видео). Доступ извне по статичному IP, 8000 порт, протокол TCP.

Ниже я приведу пример на PHP, но ЯП не важен, смысл в том, что некорректный запрос приводит к пустому ответу. Я просканировал Wireshark-ом сетевую активность и подставил данные которые отправляет официальная программа работы с камерой. И в ответ что-то разумное приходит. Максимум чем мне это поможет - это знать что не вырубили свет и может быть камера работает.
Понятное дело, что пакеты шифруются, при обращении происходит авторизация по логину/паролю прежде чем получить доступ к статусу.

Собственно сам вопрос: **Какие, в каком формате данные слать, чем шифровать/расшифровывать.**

Гугл не помог, по каким ключевым словам искать не знаю.

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("217.XXX.XXX.178", 8000, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if (!$fp) { 
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {    
    $str = '000000545a00000000000000000100000401304900000000200110ac0000000000000700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
    $out =  hexToStr($str);
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echostrToHex(fgets($fp))."\r\n";
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если верить [даташиту](http://www.hikvision.com/UploadFile/image/2014032411124257029.pdf), эта камера поддерживает протокол `RTSP`. С помощью PHP или иного языка, запустите `ffmpeg` или `openRTSP` на сервере, натравите его на поток типа `rtsp://camera.ip.address:554//Streaming/Channels/1`. Получите статус трансляции и сможете захватить оттуда кадры.

Answer (score 1):

У этой камеры для управления есть HTTP-интерфейс - отловить запросы происходящие при различных действиях гораздо проще.

Для использования же проприетарного протокола, по которому происходит общение через порт 8000, у производителя существует [Player SDK](http://www.hikvision.com/europe/download.asp?navid=1).

Со стримингом же всё даже проще - если верить информации с [Wiki ZoneMinder](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Hikvision_DS-2CD2012-I), достаточно принимать с камеры RTSP-поток по адресу вида:

```
 rtsp://<имя_пользователя>:<пароль>@<ip_камеры>:<порт>/Streaming/Channels/1?tcp
```

Comment: Отлично! Подумал я уведев "Web3.0_development_kit" в списке SDK, это то, что мне нужно! Но нет.

Comment: Там многофункциональный пульт управления полетом, но авторизация там идет через http протокол в открытом виде по спецаильной ссылке, которая у меня не доступна (поэтому ничего не работает). А хотелось бы использовать механизм который использует официальная программа iVMS-4000. Там все запросы через TCP идут.

Comment: Вру, ссылка доступна, просто тулза отправляет три раза запрос на авторизацию, причем первый раз с пустыми значениями, но в ответ получает отказ.

Comment: @alexander, вам имено Player SDK нужно использовать, как я и предлагал изначально - он и используется "официальной программой" для общения с камерой.